# Output complex state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state

I have created a complex state with different types like Checkbox, Slider or Rating (Material-UI). I would like to output them, that the user is seeing his choices.

I have created a sandbox for better understanding: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/project-forked-j81jp) In line 261 in Form.js I would output the personality data.

```
 const personalty = {
    personaltyfields:[
        {
          "description": "Ich arbeite gerne: ",
          "options": [
            {"name":"Strukturiert",   "name2":"Kreativ",            "value":50,     "type": "Slider"}

            ]
        },
        {
          "description": "Welches Motto beschreibt dich am Besten? ",
          "options": [  
            {"name":"Es lebe der Sport!",                  "value": false,    "type": "Checkbox"},
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "description": "Besonders wichtig ist mir: ",
          "options": [
            {"name":"Weiterbildungen",                               "value": 0,    "type": "Rating"},
            {"name":"junges Team",                                   "value": 0,    "type": "Rating"
          ]
        },
```

How is the correct way to output them? I could filter the checkboxes to the true clicked. The Slider could be 0 or 100. and the Rating Value is between 1-5. I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: To where do you want to output them?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Do you want to know how to loop over you data set to access the nested values? Or is it about how to render your data in React? Or about your Reducer function? Please help us out with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

My question was how to render my data, that is selected from the user. I filtered for the right value. I filter it.

`const checkedSlider = output2.options.filter((elem) => elem.value === 100 ||  elem.value === 0 && elem.type === "Slider");`

I didnt now how to filter multiple values.